# Explain me this two steps, which are used for make shared library

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

i did these steps and make shared library.
but here i have some questions

1. i want know why we write 4 and 5 steps.

   i know only that these steps is used for link library
2. in 6th step why we use only lhuffman insted of libhuffman

steps:

```
1 gcc -c -fPIC filebits.c -o filebits.o
2 gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libhuff.so.1 -o libhuffman.so.1.0.1 filebits.o
3 mv libhuffman.so.1.0.1 /home/mydesktop/slib/
4 ln -sf /home/mydesktop/slib/libhuffman.so.1.0.1  /home/mydesktop/slib/libhuffman.so
5 ln -sf /home/mydesktop/slib/libhuffman.so.1.0.1  /home/mydesktop/slib/libhuffman.so.1
6 gcc -o app app.c -lhuffman
7 ./app
```

please explain me these steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 1. i want know why we write 4 and 5 steps.
```

In step 4 you are creating a soft link to the library name which is looked up by the linker to link.
In step 5 you are creating a soft link to the library indicating its *major* version. There is no need for you to follow these steps as such instead you can generate `libhuffman.so` as the output in the first step which is what the linker looks up for. But this convention is followed so that library's major & minor versions are tracked easily. Generally, library has the name as `library_name.MAJOR_VERSION.MINOR_VERSION`. There is soft link to that in the form of `library_name.MAJOR_VERSION` & another soft link with just `library_name`. `library_name` is in the form of *lib*[library_name].*so* as that is format expected by the linker when using `-l` option. You can check libraries on your Linux PC you will see this convention being followed in a lot of cases. This [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-shlibs/index.html) provides some details regarding this.

```
2.in 6th step why we use only lhuffman insted of libhuffman
```

[GCC linker adds *lib* & *.a* (or *.so*) to the library name which is specified with `-l` option.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Your linker options are wrong when you build your library:

```
-Wl,-soname,libhuff.so.1
```

should be

```
-Wl,-soname,libhuffman.so.1
```

From the [fine manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options):

> `-soname`=*name*
>   [...] when the executable is run the dynamic linker will attempt to load the shared object specified by the DT_SONAME field rather than the using the file name given to the linker.

Comment: sorry i forgot this thing.. thanx for that